# Building TensorFlow from source on Ubuntu 16.04 w/ GPU: `GLIBCXX_3.4.20' not found

Tags: ubuntu, installation, tensorflow, anaconda, bazel

I'm on Ubuntu 16.04 and am trying to build TensorFlow with GPU support from source according to [this](https://alliseesolutions.wordpress.com/2016/09/08/install-gpu-tensorflow-from-sources-w-ubuntu-16-04-and-cuda-8-0-rc/). Everything works fine until the "Build TensorFlow" step, in which I execute:

```
bazel build -c opt --config=cuda //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package
```

The compilation hits an error with output:

```
ERROR: /home/thomas/tensorflow/tensorflow/core/BUILD:978:28: Executing genrule //tensorflow/core:proto_text_srcs_all failed: bash failed: error executing command /bin/bash -c ... (remaining 1 argument(s) skipped): com.google.devtools.build.lib.shell.BadExitStatusException: Process exited with status 1.
bazel-out/host/bin/tensorflow/tools/proto_text/gen_proto_text_functions: /home/thomas/anaconda2/lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.20' not found (required by bazel-out/host/bin/tensorflow/tools/proto_text/gen_proto_text_functions)
bazel-out/host/bin/tensorflow/tools/proto_text/gen_proto_text_functions: /home/thomas/anaconda2/lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.8' not found (required by bazel-out/host/bin/tensorflow/tools/proto_text/gen_proto_text_functions)
bazel-out/host/bin/tensorflow/tools/proto_text/gen_proto_text_functions: /home/thomas/anaconda2/lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by bazel-out/host/bin/tensorflow/tools/proto_text/gen_proto_text_functions)
Target //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package failed to build
Use --verbose_failures to see the command lines of failed build steps.
```

My suspicion is that the error has something to do with anaconda since bazel seems to be looking for libstdc++.so from within ~/anaconda2/lib.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This command seemed to fix my problem:

```
conda install libgcc
```

from [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/575505/glibcxx-3-4-20-not-found-how-to-fix-this-error).

Answer (score 3):

EDIT : Feynman27's solution seems cleaner, try it first.

Had the same issue. These steps have solved it for me (root, add sudo when needed):

1. Get the newest libstdc++ 6 available (MAY NOT BE REQUIRED):

   `add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test
   apt-get update
   apt-get upgrade`
2. Update the symlinks in ananconda, I did it in my python2 env in anaconda, maybe you need to do it in ~/anaconda/lib directly:

   `cd ~/anaconda2/envs/python2/lib
    mv libstdc++.so libstdc++.so.backup
    mv libstdc++.so.6 libstdc++.so.6.backup
    ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 libstdc++.so
    ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 libstdc++.so.6`

Comment: Rereading your question, I realised that the error I got was only when trying to import tensorflow in python, not while installing (I did that yesterday, don't remember such error). Anyways, I think these steps are worth a try

Comment: For me it helped setting up the library path to point to Anacondas library folder:  LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$HOME/anaconda2/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH      or LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$HOME/anaconda3/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH for anaconda3 repsectively