# what version of GCC does pyTables 3.4.2 require

Tags: python, pytables, rootpy

Background:

I am trying to use [`pytables`](http://www.pytables.org/) in conjunction with [`rootpy`](http://www.rootpy.org/install.html) in order to convert [`ROOT`](https://root.cern.ch/) files into `hdf5` files.

I am constrained to using `gcc 4.4.7` and therefore cannot upgrade to `ROOT6` if it requires a `gcc` upgrade.

Problem:

I have installed `pyTables` via conda in a Python 2.7.13 environment.  When I import tables I get something like:

```
>>> import tables
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/home/phys/villaa/python/anaconda3/envs/py27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tables/__init__.py", line 90, in <module>
   from .utilsextension import (
ImportError: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.9' not found (required by /home/phys/villaa/python/anaconda3/envs/py27/lib/python2.7      /site-packages/tables/utilsextension.so)
 >>>
```

I did some googling on this error and [am now tentatively considering this to be a compiler issue](https://github.com/AllenDowney/ThinkStats2/issues/92).  So I am wondering how I find the `gcc` requirements for `pyTables`, because I haven't been able to find any documentation on that so far.  What are the gcc dependency requirements for `pyTables`?

I've also seen [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39844772/cxxabi-1-3-8-not-found-in-tensorflow-gpu-install-from-source), but cannot fully understand it.  It seems like I would want to use Anaconda's `libstdc++` in my case -- because I can't update my systems compiler. It seems like my `conda` environment claims to have higher compiler values than my system:

```
(py27) cdms3:~ villaa$conda list |grep gcc
gcc                       4.8.2                        25    nlesc
libgcc                    7.2.0                h69d50b8_2  
libgcc-ng                 7.2.0                h7cc24e2_2  
root                      6.04             py2.7_gcc4.8.2    nlesc
```