# ImportError: /lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.9' not found

Tags: python

I am getting the following error:

> ImportError: /lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.9' not found (required by /home/wasiahmad/software/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/_path.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)

at this line:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

I have visited issues reported in Github and StackOverflow and followed them but still couldn't solve the problem.

Solutions checked:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/41703611/5352399
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/39856855/5352399
- https://github.com/AllenDowney/ThinkStats2/issues/92 (exactly facing this issue but the provided solution didn't work for me)

I have checked that the file: `libstdc++.so.6` is located at `/home/wasiahmad/software/anaconda3/lib/` and I ran the following command:

```
$ strings ~/software/anaconda3/lib/libstdc++.so.6 | grep CXXABI_1.3.9
```

and it returns `CXXABI_1.3.9`.

But I still can't figure out what is the problem. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I guess you will have to include  `/home/wasiahmad/software/anaconda3/lib/`  in the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` ... Be aware that `/lib64/libstdc++.so.6` currently comes first in "LD_LIBRARY_PATH".

Comment: Charlie Parker: `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/wasiahmad/software/anaconda3/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` ....... then the "new libstdc++.so.6" in 'anaconda3/lib' is first in the search path.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Adding `/home/wasiahmad/software/anaconda3/lib/` to the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` solved the problem. Thanks to [Knud Larsen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4491743/knud-larsen) for his comment and the reminder that `/lib64/libstdc++.so.6` currently comes first in `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

Comment: @Knud I receive similar error while spacy is imported. I was wondering if you have suggestions since my program still pick/s lib64/libstdc++.so.6 eventhough I have defined the property in the top level script as os.environ['LD_LIBRARY_PATH'] = '/conda/env/path'

Comment: export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/your/path/to/conda/env/lib @CharlieParker

Answer (score 28):

I totally agree with the accepted answer from @wasi-ahmad.

More specifically, typing

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/home/wasiahmad/software/anaconda3/lib/
```

in the terminal will solve the problem

Comment: Use of (previous response) is not appropriate. Because, in future place of answers will be changed based on Stack Overflow ranking system.

Answer (score 12):

if you are in a HPC this worked for me I think:

```
module load gcc/9.2.0
```

Comment: Put this at the top of my sbatch script and it worked (but with a different version of gcc I had access to), thanks.

Comment: this helped me on my Hazel HPC cluster, for anyone else looking.

Answer (score 0):

For the C++ guys: 
Run the following at same place where you are compiling your program

> export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=../lib_start/:/usr/local/lib:/usr/local/lib64