# ImportError: libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.9' not found (required by...)

Tags: anaconda, python-3.6, importerror, conda, libstdc++

I installed a Python package (auto-sklearn) in my linux machine on AWS. The installation is shown successful, but when I try to use it in Python by calling "import autosklearn", I get the following ImportError:

ImportError: /home/myname/.conda/envs/myenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scipy/sparse/../../../../libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.9' not found (required by /home/myname/.conda/envs/myenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scipy/sparse/_sparsetools.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)

I then searched online where I found [this post](https://github.com/widdowquinn/pyani/issues/96). I tried their recommended methods to reset LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib64/:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH

However it's not working.

I'm not sure if I did something wrong to reset LD_LIBRARY_PATH? Do I reset LD_LIBRARY_PATH in terminal?

How can I fix this issue in general? I already updated to Anaconda distribution 5 according [this post,](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/5191) that should have included libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.9' according to the author.

Thanks!

Python 3.6
Conda

Comment: I solved it by "module load compilers/gcc-9.2" (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49875588/importerror-lib64-libstdc-so-6-version-cxxabi-1-3-9-not-found)

Answer (score 4):

I was also facing same problem. I solved it by updating the scipy using `pip install -U scipy`

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem with HPC and solved it by loading gcc module as below:

module load compilers/gcc-9.2.

Hope it helps.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).