# Anaconda ImportError: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found

Tags: python, c++, tensorflow, anaconda, glibc

I am getting the following import error when I am trying to run a Python script in a conda environment

```
(squad) azada@scholar-fe00:~/Desktop/Toy-Problem-Team-2 $ python3 train.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train.py", line 21, in <module>
    from tensorboardX import SummaryWriter
  File "/home/azada/miniconda3/envs/squad/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorboardX/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from .torchvis import TorchVis
  File "/home/azada/miniconda3/envs/squad/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorboardX/torchvis.py", line 11, in <module>
    from .writer import SummaryWriter
  File "/home/azada/miniconda3/envs/squad/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorboardX/writer.py", line 15, in <module>
    from .event_file_writer import EventFileWriter
  File "/home/azada/miniconda3/envs/squad/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorboardX/event_file_writer.py", line 28, in <module>
    from .proto import event_pb2
  File "/home/azada/miniconda3/envs/squad/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorboardX/proto/event_pb2.py", line 7, in <module>
    from google.protobuf import descriptor as _descriptor
  File "/home/azada/miniconda3/envs/squad/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/protobuf/descriptor.py", line 47, in <module>
    from google.protobuf.pyext import _message
ImportError: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by /home/azada/miniconda3/envs/squad/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/protobuf/pyext/_message.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)
```

Writing the `strings /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 | grep GLIBCXX` command has the following output

```
GLIBCXX_3.4
GLIBCXX_3.4.1
GLIBCXX_3.4.2
GLIBCXX_3.4.3
GLIBCXX_3.4.4
GLIBCXX_3.4.5
GLIBCXX_3.4.6
GLIBCXX_3.4.7
GLIBCXX_3.4.8
GLIBCXX_3.4.9
GLIBCXX_3.4.10
GLIBCXX_3.4.11
GLIBCXX_3.4.12
GLIBCXX_3.4.13
GLIBCXX_3.4.14
GLIBCXX_3.4.15
GLIBCXX_3.4.16
GLIBCXX_3.4.17
GLIBCXX_3.4.18
GLIBCXX_3.4.19
GLIBCXX_DEBUG_MESSAGE_LENGTH
```

As you can see the required `libgcc` version is not present. But I am unable to understand why python is looking for `GLIBCXX` in the `/usr` directory?

Running the same command on the `libstdc++.so.6` of my anaconda environment shows that the required version is present in the file.

I am using my university's computing cluster so I don't have the admin rights.

Is there any way that I can make Python use the `libstdc++` of my conda environment instead of the one in the `/usr` directory?

Answer (score 64):

I spent a day working on this having encountered the same exact problem working on my research university's computing cluster with the same specs as you, and I finally found the right Stack Overflow [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49875588/importerror-lib64-libstdc-so-6-version-cxxabi-1-3-9-not-found). None of the above answers here work, unfortunately, but I can say with *very* high confidence that the details in the linked thread should solve your problem even though the source of the error traceback was different.

To summarize, you'll need to add the path to the `lib` folder in `anaconda` to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/your/path/to/conda/env/lib
```

In my case, I just did:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:~/anaconda3/lib
```

...and it worked like a charm!

Comment: To make the conda env automatically set/unset variables upon activating/deacivating, see this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46826497/conda-set-ld-library-path-for-env-only)

Comment: For tcsh what worked for me put `setenv LD_LIBRARY_PATH ~/path/to/miniconda3/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` in `~/.tcshrc` then `source ~/.tcshrc`

Comment: To automate the path export use:
`echo 'export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:$CONDA_PREFIX/lib/' > $CONDA_PREFIX/etc/conda/activate.d/env_vars.sh`

Answer (score 13):

This is also worth a shot, since it was what ended up working for me:

```
conda install -c conda-forge libstdcxx-ng
```

Explanation: I got this error when trying to `import tensorflow as tf`:

```
ImportError: /opt/conda/bin/../lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.30' not found (required by /opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so)
```

and I already had `libgcc-ng` installed. It's also worth noting that I had added both conda library path and system library paths appended to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, but that did not work for me. So, YMMV.

Comment: The most voted answer didn't work for me, this worked like a charm!

Comment: Also the solution for me to fix my qgis install done with `conda install -c conda-forge qgis`

Answer (score 2):

solve it by downgrading to libgcc==5.2.0

Initially, try to install with pip but if you get  the error: **Could not download and compile the C core of igraph..** install it by **conda**

Comment: The version is not available
`(squad) azada@scholar-fe00:~/Desktop/Toy-Problem-Team-2 $ conda search libgcc
Loading channels: done
# Name                       Version           Build  Channel             
libgcc                         7.2.0      h69d50b8_2  pkgs/main `

Comment: try those commands :
conda install -c conda-forge igraph python-igraph
conda install -c vtraag leidenalg
 conda install libgcc==7.2.0

Answer (score -3):

Run this code and your problem should be solved,

```
conda install -c conda-forge gcc
```