# ImportError: /lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.9' not found when loading pandas in reticulate

Tags: python, r, pandas, rstudio-server, reticulate

I have seen this posted a few times but I haven't seen a clear answer that is working for my situation, so forgive me if reposting (see: https://community.rstudio.com/t/reticulate-issues-in-rstudio-server/16555 & [ImportError: /lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.9' not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49875588/importerror-lib64-libstdc-so-6-version-cxxabi-1-3-9-not-found) & https://github.com/rstudio/reticulate/issues/428)

I am trying to load a `.pickle` file with a `pandas` dataframe into `R` with `reticulate`.

However, whenever I try to import `pandas`, the following error gets thrown:

**#Error**

```
> pd <- import("pandas")
> Error in py_module_import(module, convert = convert) : ImportError: /lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.9' not found (required by /Users/thomas/Python/mambaforge/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/_libs/window/aggregations.cpython-310-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)
```

Which I assume stems from trying to call the "default" library path on the server where our RStudio-Server instance is initialized.

I have tried multiple methods to address this in both the rmarkdown in the Quarto document I'm using, and the `.Rprofile` that is called prior to initializing any part of the project as described below:

```
#In .Rprofile
Sys.setenv(PATH = paste("/Users/thomas/Python/mambaforge/bin/",Sys.getenv()["PATH"],sep=";"))
Sys.setenv(RETICULATE_PYTHON = "/Users/thomas/Python/mambaforge/bin/python3")
Sys.setenv(LD_LIBRARY_PATH = "/Users/thomas/Python/mambaforge/lib/")
source("renv/activate.R")
#use_python("/Users/thomas/Python/mambaforge/bin/python3")
```

```
#In Markdown file
PATH <- Sys.getenv("PATH")
RETICULATE_PYTHON <- Sys.getenv("RETICULATE_PYTHON")
LD_LIBRARY_PATH <- Sys.getenv("LD_LIBRARY_PATH")
use_condaenv(condaenv = "base")
system("export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/Users/thomas/Python/mambaforge/lib/")
pd <- import("pandas")
```

However, the error seems to persist regardless of what path redirection I may call or what environment variables I may actively set.

Would anyone know how I might be able to address this error?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Below is the versioning information for the RStudio-Server session, R installation, py_config() output, and server OS.

**RStudio Server**

```
2022.07.0+548 "Spotted Wakerobin" Release (34ea3031089fa4e38738a9256d6fa6d70629c822, 2022-07-06) for CentOS 7
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/116.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
```

**R Version**

```
platform       x86_64-pc-linux-gnu         
arch           x86_64                      
os             linux-gnu                   
system         x86_64, linux-gnu           
status                                     
major          4                           
minor          2.1                         
year           2022                        
month          06                          
day            23                          
svn rev        82513                       
language       R                           
version.string R version 4.2.1 (2022-06-23)
nickname       Funny-Looking Kid
```

**py_config() output:**

```
python:         /Users/thomas/Python/mambaforge/bin/python3
libpython:      /Users/thomas/Python/mambaforge/lib/libpython3.10.so
pythonhome:     /Users/thomas/Python/mambaforge:/Users/thomas/Python/mambaforge
version:        3.10.10 | packaged by conda-forge | (main, Mar 24 2023, 20:08:06) [GCC 11.3.0]
numpy:          /Users/thomas/Python/mambaforge/lib/python3.10/site-packages/numpy
numpy_version:  1.25.1
pandas:         /Users/thomas/Python/mambaforge/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas

NOTE: Python version was forced by RETICULATE_PYTHON
```

**OS Version:**

```
NAME="Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server"
VERSION="7.9 (Maipo)"
ID="rhel"
ID_LIKE="fedora"
VARIANT="Server"
VARIANT_ID="server"
VERSION_ID="7.9"
PRETTY_NAME="Red Hat Enterprise Linux"
ANSI_COLOR="0;31"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:redhat:enterprise_linux:7.9:GA:server"
HOME_URL="https://www.redhat.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugzilla.redhat.com/"

REDHAT_BUGZILLA_PRODUCT="Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7"
REDHAT_BUGZILLA_PRODUCT_VERSION=7.9
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT="Red Hat Enterprise Linux"
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT_VERSION="7.9"
```